# render a map's size in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have two maps that I want to use their length as an integer for a component in react. the code looks something like this:

```
function Test() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [spacing, setSpacing] = React.useState(2);
  // FETCH REQUEST DATABASE ITEMS
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/test")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(items => setItems(items));
  }, []);
  // ASSIGN ITEMS TO MAPPED GRID
  return (
    <Grid
      container
      direction="row"
      justify="space-around"
      alignItems="flex-start"
      spacing={2}
    >
      {items.map(x => {
        return (
          <Grid item sm key={`key${x._id}`}>
            <SmallCard
              key={x._id}

              // MAP I WANT TO TURN INTO INTEGER BELLOW

              mappedItemCount = {x.map.size}

              // ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ THIS PART HERE IN PARTICULAR


            />
          </Grid>
        );
      })}
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

For some reason this does not seem to turn it into an integer and still lists as NAN. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like `items` is an array, not a map.

Comment: items is an array yes, but the contents inside the array contain a mapped object. That's where this issue lies. if I render it without adding size I get a crashing error that says "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: Ok, that makes some sense.  Can you please add at least one of the Map items to your question?  Additionally, you would want `x.size` if it's a Map.  As you have it, it's trying to use the Array `map` function, which won't work with a Map.

Comment: "likes":{"undefined":"5dc45b3bb32166125e993801"},"dislikes":{},

this is two of the mapped items from the json being sent over. So if i want to use size, I cant return everything in a mapped function? WHat about a for loop?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you meant by "Can you please add at least one of the Map items to your question?"

Answer (score 0):

my item was an object not a map due to the way its being rendered. so the correct syntax should really be the following:

```
mappedItemCount = {Object.keys(x.map.size).length}
```

Sacred texts can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys